# How to remove an entry from a std::map using key?

Tags: c++11, stl, containers

I am having a following a map,

```
struct details;

map<std::string, details> myMap;

myMap.erase(“key”);// Why I cant do this in C++11?
```

This is so simple in java

```
Map<std::string, details> map
map.remove(“key");
```

How can I delete an entry from a std::map using key?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, you can't? What's stopping you, exactly? `myMap.erase("key");` should work just fine. Note though that you have fancy curly quotes `“”` where regular quotes `""` should be - could that be your problem?

Comment: Actually you can. What the specific error message did you get?

Comment: I get compiler error, No matching constructor to call erase

Comment: 'std::map<std::string, incident_information> const incidentDetails; ‘ std::string IncidentIdToDelete; incidentDetails.erase(IncidentIdToDelete); This is the actual map I am using.

Comment: @Kid your map is `const`, so indeed you can't modify it by removing an element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin Hi thanks you are correct, it is build now. But now it started throwing error for this 'incidentDetails.insert(IncidentIdToAdd,pIncidentInformationContent )'.  Same error no matching member function.

Comment: @Kid helping you through fragments of information stuffed in comments is not really how this site works. Please make a question of it, with a [mcve], so you can get more effective help.

Comment: @Kid [`map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

Comment: Thanks for the reference http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Why not use the [online documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase)...?

Answer (score 4):

## How to remove an entry from a std::map using key?

Call the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) member function on the `std::map<Key>` container using the `erase(const Key& key)` form just like had been shown:

```cpp
myMap.erase("key");
```

Alternatively, go through the extra steps necessary for finding the entry and erasing by iterator. Here's an example of this:

```cpp
const auto it = myMap.find("key");
if (it != myMap.end())
    myMap.erase(it);
```

As @FriskySaga points out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230318/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-stdmap-using-key/42231247#comment124685274_42231247), only call `erase` with the returned iterator if it's not the `end()` iterator.

## Why I cant do this in C++11?

The container `myMap` has to be modifiable. I.e. it cannot be marked `const`. Otherwise, you'll get a [compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/ob7jdcjvK).

In the [Feb 14, 2017 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230318/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-stdmap-using-key/42231247#comment71620783_42230318), @Kid shared that `std::map<std::string, incident_information> const incidentDetails` was the actual map they were using. @Quentin rightly recognizes in their [response comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230318/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-stdmap-using-key/42231247#comment71620825_42230318) that this map - that is `const` - can't be modified. Trying to use `erase` results in a compiler error as @Kid realizes in their [follow up comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230318/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-stdmap-using-key/42231247#comment71623563_42231247).

Comment: Btw you can also use `pop(...)` if the element that is to be removed needs to be handled further down the line.

Comment: This question has been answered already. Please see the comments. Thanks anyway.

Comment: For future readers: Note that if `myMap.find("key")` yields the `end()` iterator, then undefined behavior will occur. [See the footnote here.](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/)